# Understand how CONTINUE works in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, continue

I'm reading an article on the [MDN website about loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#while_statement). I'm trying to understand why we are getting the 1, 3, 7, 12 as a result from the following?:

```
var i = 0;
var n = 0;
while (i < 5) {
 i++;
  if (i == 3) {
  continue;
  }
 n += i;
}
```

Wouldn't the continue statement cause it to skip 3?

Comment: What exactly is  `1, 3, 7, 12`?

Comment: You are skipping the 3rd iteration but the 3 is from `1 + 2`

Answer (score 2):

What `continue` does is immediately jump to the top of your loop. Essentially, it ignores everything following it and moves on to the next iteration.

To give a simpler example, here's how to print only the even numbers in a range:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // If i isn't even, skip to the next iteration
  if (i % 2 !== 0) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log(i);
}
```

Because of this, you are not adding 3 to your running sum. Instead, you essentially get:

```
var i = 0;
var n = 0;
i++; // 1
n += i; // 1

i++; // 2
n += i; // 3

i++; // 3
// skip 3

i++; // 4
n += i; // 7

i++; // 5
n += i; // 12
```

Comment: great explanation. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. When i equals 3, the loop is skipped.
The Focus is rather on n, which has the values 1, 3, 7, 12

Answer (score 0):

I've overlooked the assignment operator in this example (+=).

As we loop it progresses as follows:

After the first loop, x=1 and y=1, we progress and add another 1 to x which now = 2. Due to the assignment operator (n += x) we add two(x) to one(y).

At this stage we loop again and the operation realises that x has become three, so it 'skips' that assignment operator and continues.